# Achieving multiple plots with different plotting widths in R

Tags: r, plot

I want to create multiple plots in a single plotting window in which the width of the panels of each plot are proportional to xlim of each plot.

At the moment I use:

```
layout(matrix(c(1:8,10,9), 5, 2, byrow = FALSE), widths=2)       
layout.show(10)
```

Basically, I would like `width` to be applied individually to each plot rather than to all the plots in a column. What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Can you fix your example so that the matrix passed to `layout` is actually valid input? If the largest integer is 10, it has to contain 1-9 as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`layout` only works if the plots can be arranged over a regular grid,
but they need not have the same widths.

```
layout(
  matrix(
    c(1,1,2,3,3,2,4,5,5,6,6,6), 
    nc=3, byrow = TRUE
  )
)
layout.show(6)
```

If you want something really irregular, you can use `par(fig=...,new=TRUE)`.

```
plot.new()
par(mar=c(2,2,1,1))
k <- 4
f <- function() 
  plot(rnorm(20),rnorm(20), xlab="", ylab="", main="", las=1)
for(i in 1:k) {
  par(fig=c(0,i/(k+1), (i-1)/k, i/k), new=TRUE)
  f()
  par(fig=c(i/(k+1),1, (i-1)/k, i/k), new=TRUE)
  f()
}
```