# R_controlling size of the plot in a multiple plot window

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to include two plot in a single window using `mfrow`in `par()`. 
something like this

```
x=1:10
y=seq(10,100,10)
z=seq(100,1000,100)

par(mfrow=c(2,1))
par(mar=c(0.2,4.1,4.1,2.1))
plot(x,y,xaxt="n",xlab=NA)
par(mar=c(4.1,4.1,0.2,2.1))
plot(x,z)
```

which gives
[image]

Now let's say I want to adjust the height of second plot as small as half the height of the first plot. How can I do it? I was trying with many `par()` parameters. But I couldn't find a way.

Comment: This link may be useful `<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858074/achieving-multiple-plots-with-different-plotting-widths-in-r>`

Comment: I suggest using `layout()` rather than messing with `par()~